# why does onClientClick="window.open("dest.aspx")" refresh my current page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation

okay, so i am using this

```
onClientClick="window.open("dest.aspx")"
```

in a button attribute. it is serving the purpose by opening the target link in new tab but at the same time it is reloading my current page which is undesired.

why is this happening?
help, please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
onClientClick="window.open("dest.aspx");return false"
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. i will mark it as an answer when they let me.

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for a reference of the parameters to window.open.

Comment: All though this answer gives information about parameters in window.open, it does not talk about stopping the page relaod.